# How do I check in shapeless if a type is a member of an HList?

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

I'm doing a sequence of preprocessing steps on strings and I was thinking of using `HList`s to improve the safety of my steps. Some processing steps must be run after others, so I was thinking of encoding that in the type system. My first attempt was:

```
trait Step
trait Raw extends Step
trait A extends Step
trait B extends Step
trait DependsOnA extends Step
trait DependsOnB extends Step

case class ToBeProcessed[S <: Step](value: String)

object ToBeProcessed {
    def raw(input: String): ToBeProcessed[Raw] = ...
    def doA(input: ToBeProcessed[Raw]): ToBeProcessed[A] = ...
    def doB(input: ToBeProcessed[A]): ToBeProcessed[B] = ...
    def doDependsOnA(input: ToBeProcessed[B]): ToBeProcessed[DependsOnA] = ...
    def doDependsOnB(input: ToBeProcessed[DependsOnA]): ToBeProcessed[DependsOnB] = ...
}
```

This works, because it forces me to call everything in the sequence `doA` > `doB` > `doDependsOnA` > `doDependsOnB`, which is a possible order in which it works, but:

1. it forces dependence between steps that do not depend on each other
2. if I want to implement a new intermediate step `doC` I must change the types of things that are unrelated to it

So I started reading about type level lists in Haskell and realized I could use that to encode my dependencies. So I started reading on Shapeless `HList`s and this popped out:

```
case class ToBeProcessed[S <: HList](value: String)

object ToBeProcessed {
    def raw(input: String): ToBeProcessed[Raw :: HNil] = ...
    def doA[S <: HList](input: ToBeProcessed[S]): ToBeProcessed[A :: S] = ...
    def doB[S <: HList](input: ToBeProcessed[S]): ToBeProcessed[B :: S] = ...
```

And to encode the dependency I must have a way to check that A is contained in a given HList:

```
    def doDependsOnA[S <: HList, ???](input: ToBeProcessed[S]): ToBeProcessed[DependsOnA :: S] = ...

}
```

where in the `???` type I must somehow encode that `S` contains `A`. I'm still not sure how do I do that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shapeless already has a typeclass for proving that a `HList` contains a certain type: `Selector`. You would use it like this:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.Selector

def doDependsOnA[S <: HList](input: ToBeProcessed[S])(implicit ev: Selector[S,A]): ToBeProcessed[DependsOnA :: S] = ???
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a bunch. I was earlier today looking into the code of shapeless looking for it but didn't stumbled upon this.